# How to make mongodb select the secondary mongo from the replication set if one db in the set fails

Tags: java, mongodb, replicaset

I am working on a java application which is trying to read from mongodb. I am using two secondary mongodbs and if one of the db fails, it has to automatically initiate read from the other one. While testing this code I ran into error **com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms** when I stop one of the secondary db(purposefully crashing). What I assume is, the application is not initiating connection to the other mongo.
I am at my wits end here and I could use some help. Here's the code snippet of my java application.

```
initiated=false;
if(initiated){
            mongoClient.close();
        mongoClient = null;
}
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverSeeds);
        if(isSlaveOk()){
            DBObject use = new BasicDBObject("use", "rebel");
            DBObject id = new BasicDBObject("id","1");
            mongoClient.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred(use, id));
        }
        db = mongoClient.getDB(getDbName());
        collection = db.getCollection(getDbCollectionName());
        initiated = true;
```

Comment: So, I get it right: you have two secondaries and a primary, 3 members altogether?

Comment: The serverSeeds is a list consisting of ips to secondaries only. In my application we want to read only from the Secondary ones. But in the Mongo Configuration we do have 1 primary, 2 secondaries and 1 arbiter.